# Implement overloaded method in Java

Tags: java, overriding, overloading, data-objects

I have following structure:

```
public abstract class A{

    public abstract DataObject methodA(arg0) throws SQLException;

    public abstract DataObect methodA(arg0, arg1) throws SQLExcpetion;

}
```

Here I want to implement overloaded methodA so that not all the sub classes has to implement overloaded method. In addition, there is nothing that I want to return from overloaded methodA. Is there a way that I can return some dummy dataObject and not affect the actual DataObject returned by the subclass?

Thanks

Comment: And why are you trying to give a method body to an abstract method? Your question is *very* unclear.

Comment: why not, `return null`